# how to get permissions information from a java.lang.SecurityManager?

Tags: java, java-7, securitymanager

I am doing some debugging in an application (not applet) and have obtained the system's security manager via a call to **System.getSecurityManager()**. How can I print all configuration information that this **SecurityManager** was setup with? Looking at the [Java 7 SE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) it seems that all methods are interrogatory in nature and there is no way to get the permissions configuration. The **toString()** method also seems to inherit directly from **Object** and just prints the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Run the program with -Djava.security.debug=access,domain and you will see everything you need to see.

Comment: He could be simply `sign` his `jar` file. And moreover we don't know whether he's programming an `application` or an `applet`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati That won't stop it printing out all the access information, including the entire security domain configuration.

Comment: It's an application. I just edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: I tried that, there's no change in the output. I am not inside a debugger. I'm just trying to find a method to print a comprehensive listing of Security Manager's configuration / settings / permissions. SecurityManager#toString doesn't do anything useful, and like I said at the original message I don't see any methods in java.lang.SecurityManager that can give me what I need. What API/methods, exactly, are you proposing that I use when I run my code with -Djava.security.debug=access,domain ??

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas You mean that option printed *nothing?* Contrary to everything it says in the Javadoc?

Comment: No, there's no difference in the output whether I use -Djava.security.debug=access,domain or not.

Answer (score -1):

See it here. [`http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html)

There also exists another method of checking the permissions. Use a try catch block.

```
try{

} catch (Exception e){
    if (e instanceof SecurityException){
        // It's a security violation.
        // Look for another possibility
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your citation doesn't provide any kind of an answer. And why wouldn't you just catch SecurityException and avoid the 'instanceof' test?

Comment: @EJP I've not omitted the `instanceof` test. I don't know what work he's doing which get's him a security exception. So I've added a comment to look for another possibility of the same work which do not get a security exception. He could instead `sign` his `.jar` files

Comment: You haven't addressed my comment or answered my question in any way. -1.